# GraphQL / Apollo partial update send full object block with null

Tags: graphql, apollo

Hey folks I just got in some kind of issue. In playground everything works fine but in the app is sending all object with null fields apart of the fields I am trying to update.

So I am trying to update first and last name of the user.

This is my mutation

```
export default gql`
  mutation updateUser(
    $_id: ID!
    $email: String
    $password: String
    $firstName: String
    $lastName: String
    $phone: String
    $description: String
    $role: String
    $avatar: String
    $houseName: String
    $streetName: String
    $city: String
    $postCode: String
    $newUser: Boolean
    $expoPushToken: String
    $birthday: String
    $countryOfResidence: String
    $nationality: String
  ) {
    updateUser(
      _id: $_id
      email: $email
      password: $password
      firstName: $firstName
      lastName: $lastName
      phone: $phone
      description: $description
      role: $role
      avatar: $avatar
      houseName: $houseName
      streetName: $streetName
      city: $city
      postCode: $postCode
      newUser: $newUser
      expoPushToken: $expoPushToken
      birthday: $birthday
      countryOfResidence: $countryOfResidence
      nationality: $nationality
    ) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;
```

Here I am doing the mutation

```
this.props.updateUser(_id, firstName, lastName);

const mutationConfig = {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    updateUser: (_id, firstName, lastName) =>
      mutate({
        variables: { _id, firstName, lastName }
      })
  })
};
```

What I get in DB

```
{ email: null,
  password: null,
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  phone: null,
  description: null,
  role: null,
  avatar: null,
  houseName: null,
  streetName: null,
  city: null,
  postCode: null,
  newUser: null,
  expoPushToken: null,
  birthday: null,
  countryOfResidence: null,
  nationality: null }
```

If I do the same thing in playground

```
mutation{
  updateUser(_id: "5cd2f8612a89ff61aed9f43c", firstName: "John", lastName:"Doe"){
    _id
  }
}
```

The response look like this

```
{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
```

Any idea what can be?

**SOLVED**

I found the the only issue was from `react-apollo@2.5.5` so I got back to `react-apollo@2.4.1` until a new version is coming up

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.